# AngularJS/ c# WebAPI 405 method not allowed after URLrewrite

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, url-rewriting, cors

I'm trying to get Oath2 working in AngularJS. The issue I came across was the redirectURI was not allowed to have a # in it, So I removed it by using HTML5 Mode.

This all seemed to be working okay until you refresh any page and then you get 404 page not found.

So I've tried to fix this by using URL rewrite as contained in the post below

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1191/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-page-not-found-solution

The issue I have now is I'm getting :

```
Request URL: http://localhost/companyname/api/public/auth/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

When running the structure of the site/api are

```
localhost/*companyname*/
localhost/*companyname*/api

*domainname*/*companyname*/
*domainname*/*companyname*/api
```

The rewrite rule I have in the angularjs web.config is

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/companyname/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

I've included cors in the webapi using the following

```
  var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
  config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has a similar issue.

I had to end up writing 2 different rewrite rules one for the site and one for the api

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="API Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^api/(.*)" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/companyname/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```